# How to convert IQueryable<Int> to 'int'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am facing a problem when  trying to get the last record of my model Client in terms of the userID.

```
var user_id = (int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
        var client_id = from d in db.Connexions 
                        where d.userId == user_id
                        select d.ClientID;

        var lastClient = from d in db.Clients
                         where d.ClientID = client_id // here appears the error
                         select d;
```

For the first one there is no error but for the second request there is an error of type

Comment: "an error of type"? What is the error?

Comment: The funny part is that there are two errors here as @Exception noticed: you can neither compare `IQueryable<int>` to an `int` nor ASSIGN it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
var client_id = from d in db.Connexions 
                    where d.userId == user_id
                    select d.ClientID;
```

does not return a single int, but a lazy collection of ints fulfilling the conditions given. `client_id.First()` will give you the first id in that collection.

Comment: Thank you! It is okay I accept the first one answer just a question of time

Comment: Finally I accept your answer because the first one throw an error! Thank you again

Comment: Actually, `Take(1)` will give you a collection with one element, in this case the first, so you would need to `.First()` as well in that case.

Answer (score 3):

```
var client_id = (from d in db.Connexions 
            where d.userId == user_id
            select d.ClientID).First();
```

Comment: may be firstordefault is more appropriate in case if there is no element.

Comment: That's why I hate query syntax.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` would suit here if he would check for null later on. Since he's not (he's assuming it's always there), `First()` would throw more appropriate exception.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retrieve last record then do this :

```
var lastClient = (from d in db.Clients
                  where d.ClientID == client_id  <--- //here it should be "==" not "="
                  orderby d.UpdateTime descending
                  select d).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Okay but if I want to retrieve the last record of Client according to the userID that have entered the record